# Not able to read javascript object property such as "first-Name"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the below JSON

```
[
    { "first-Name": "John", "lastName": "Scott" },
    { "first-Name": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" },
    { "first-Name": "Lima", "lastName": "Jones" }
]
```

Specifically it contains a property `first-Name`. Now, whenever I try to get data for that particular property it throws an error.

The error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Name is not defined(anonymous function)
@ VM169:1InjectedScript._evaluateOn 
@ VM128:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap 
@ VM128:816InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame 
@ VM128:942$.ajax.success 
@ App.js:11n.Callbacks.j 
@ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith 
@ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2x 
@ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b 
@ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4
```

The way I try to get data is: `data[0].first-Name` in Chrome's console. However, if I try to get data for the property `lastName` as `data[0].lastName` is giving the output. So what is the issue and how can I fix this?

Comment: `data[0]['first-Name']` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: the problem is the '-' character, you need to use something else in the property name. Try replacing first-Name with firstName.

Comment: @SimoneRiboldi That's not a problem, this is valid JSON.

Comment: I ckecked in http://jsonlint.com/ your json is a valide one